# Why pagination with numbers is not working in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vuex

I have a problem with my Vue application with Vuex, so I'm working on pagination and the problem is that it doesn't show me my events from the store, it doesn't show me the numbers from the pagination either. The problem is also that pagination is detected on page 0, where there are no events, and not on the first page, where events should already be displayed. Would someone be so kind as to tell me where I'm doing wrong? I would be very grateful for help in solving this problem.

**index.js**

```
state: {
  limit: 12,
  page: 0,
  events: [],
},

mutations: {
  limit(state, limit) {
    state.limit = limit
  },

  page(state, page) {
   state.page = page
  },

  allEvents(state, allEvents) {
   state.events = allEvents;
  },
},

actions: {
  async fetchEvents({ commit, state }) {
      try {
        const response = await provider().clients.graphqlClientPortal.query({
          query: gql`
            query LiveEvents($limit: Int!, $page: Int!){
              liveEvents(pagination:{limit:$limit, page:$page}, order:{startsAt:{direction: DESC}}){
                total,
                data{
                  id,
                  name,
                  stub,
                  description,
                  mainImage{
                    id,
                    uri
                  },
                  location,
                  type,
                  layout
                  chat,
                  liveStream{
                    endsAt,
                    startsAt
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: {
            limit: state.limit,
            page: state.page
          },
        });
        console.log(response.data)
        commit('allEvents', response.data.liveEvents.data);
        commit("limit", response.data.liveEvents.data.limit),
        commit("page", response.data.liveEvents.page)
        //commit("total", response.data.liveEvents.total)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error-message', error.graphQLErrors)
      }
    },
}
```

**List.vue**

```
<template>
// displaying events
   <div v-for="(event, index) in displayedPosts" :key="index">
     <h2>{{ event.name }}</h2>
     <p>{{ event.location }}</p>
     ...
   </div>

// pagination with buttons and numbers
<div>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <button type="button" v-if="page != 1" @click="page--"> Previous </button>
     </li>
     <li>
       <button type="button" v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page - 1, page + 5)" :key="pageNumber"
         @click="page = pageNumber"> {{ pageNumber }} </button>
     </li>
     <li>
       <button type="button" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length"> Next </button>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "List",

  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      page: this.$store.state.page,
      perPage: this.$store.state.limit,
      pages: [],
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchEvents")
  },

  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      let events = this.$store.state.events;
      for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        this.posts.push(events[i])
      }
    },

    setPages() {
      let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.posts.length / this.perPage);
      for (let index = 1; index <= numberOfPages; index++) {
        this.pages.push(index);
      }
    },

    paginate(posts) {
      let page = this.page;
      let perPage = this.perPage;
      let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
      let to = (page * perPage);
      return posts.slice(from, to);
    }
  },

  computed: {
    displayedPosts() {
      return this.paginate(this.posts);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    posts() {
      this.setPages();
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getPosts();
  },

  filters: {
    trimWords(value) {
      return value.split(" ").splice(0, 20).join(" ") + '...';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not updating the `page` and `limit` in the Vuex store correctly. You are trying to commit the mutation with the wrong data. The `limit` and `page` are not part of the `liveEvents.data` object, they are part of the variables you sent in the query.
2. You are not watching the Vuex store for changes in the `events` state. This means that when the `events` state changes, your component does not react to these changes.
3. You are initializing `posts` in the `data` function and then pushing to it in the `getPosts` method. This is not reactive and Vue will not be able to track changes to `posts`.

Here's how you can fix these issues:

1. Update the `fetchEvents` action to commit the correct `limit` and `page`:

```js
actions: {
  async fetchEvents({ commit, state }) {
    // ...
    commit('allEvents', response.data.liveEvents.data);
    commit("limit", state.limit),
    commit("page", state.page)
    // ...
  },
}
```

2. Watch the Vuex `events` state in your component and update `posts` when it changes:

```js
watch: {
  '$store.state.events': {
    handler: function(events) {
      this.posts = events;
    },
    immediate: true,
  },
  posts() {
    this.setPages();
  }
},
```

3. Remove the `getPosts` method and the `created` lifecycle hook as they are not needed anymore.
4. Initialize `page` to 1 instead of 0 in your Vuex store:

```js
state: {
  limit: 12,
  page: 1,
  events: [],
},
```

5. Update the `paginate` method to handle the case when `page` is 0:

```js
paginate(posts) {
  let page = this.page;
  let perPage = this.perPage;
  let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
  let to = (page * perPage);
  return page > 0 ? posts.slice(from, to) : [];
}
```

6. Update the `v-if` condition in the Previous button to check if `page` is greater than 1:

```html
<button type="button" v-if="page > 1" @click="page--"> Previous </button>
```

With these changes, your pagination should work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but the pagination is not working, the events are displayed on the page and the current pagination number is 1, because I fixed it to 1 in Vuex, but no prev and next buttons are shown.